# Export using jsPDF or Canves2image the image not correct duplicating it

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas, splunk, export-to-pdf

I am trying to have export on HTML dashboard so i am using the jsPDF, am using the below script. also the chart comes out with the x-axis duplicated under each other as attached. any ideas?

html2canvas(document.getElementById("panel1"), {
             onrendered: function(canvas) {

```
             var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          //   console.log('Report Image URL: '+imgData);
             var doc = new jsPDF(); //210mm wide and 297mm high

             doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
             doc.save('sample.pdf');
         }
     });
```

screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i changed the jspdf.js with the below and it worked

NodeParser.prototype.getChildren = function(parentContainer) {
    return flatten([].filter.call(parentContainer.node.childNodes, renderableNode).map(function(node) {
        var container = [node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && node.parentElement.tagName !== "text" ? new TextContainer(node, parentContainer) : new NodeContainer(node, parentContainer)].filter(nonIgnoredElement);
        return node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && container.length && node.tagName !== "TEXTAREA" ? (container[0].isElementVisible() ? container.concat(this.getChildren(container[0])) : []) : container;
    }, this));
};